# Grouping selected rows in kendo grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm using a Kendo grid. I am programatically selecting rows from the grid.
I want to group or show selected rows together.

I am currently using following approach.

- getDatasource of grid
- get highlighted rows
- splice highlighted rows from main datasource & concatinate highlighted with spliced array
- reassign datasource to grid
- Highlight again

This is causing performance issue for me.

Comment: What is your performance issue? What seems to be causing it? Any code to share?

Comment: I have large number of rows in grid. Cant use paging as I have some synchronization to perform on these rows. [Count of rows > 10000]

Comment: Show your code so we can investigate where is the problem..

Answer (score 0):

You need to do following things to simplify above process.
Get the dataSource of Kendo grid into a variable.

You will get selected arrays using grid.select() method. For each selected row, find index in main dataSource array using indexOf method. Remove each element using dataSource.remove(item). Add again same element to index 0 using dataSouce.add(). Once this process is done for all selected element, just highlight elements first grid.select().length elements.